# Can I use fetch from the local drive with App Router in Next JS 14?

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, authentication, next.js

I keep getting a 404 error and the promised response from on message listener went out of scope.

I started trying to make an api for user authentication and was told I needed to change it to route.js so I did. Here is my route.js file under app/api/auth:

```
import { hashPassword } from "@/app/lib/auth";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../lib/db";

export async function POST(req, res) {
  const data = req.body;

  const { email, password } = data;

  if (
    !email ||
    !email.includes("@") ||
    !password ||
    password.trim().length < 7
  ) {
    res.status(422).json({
      message:
        "Invalid input - password should also be at least 7 characters long",
    });
  }

  const client = await connectToDatabase();

  const db = client.db();

  const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);

  const result = await db.collection("users").insertOne({
    email: email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  });

  res.status(201).json({ message: "Created user!" });
  client.close();
}
```

Then after making a route, I tried to connect my login/register page and get the registration part of the page working so I could register a new user with mongoDB cloud.

```
"use client";
// components/LoginForm.js
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import classes from "./login.module.css";

async function createUser(email, password) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/route", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(data.message || "Something went wrong");
  }

  return data;
}

const LoginForm = () => {
  const emailInputRef = useRef();
  const passwordInputRef = useRef();
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);

  function switchAuthModeHandler() {
    setIsLogin((prevState) => !prevState);
  }

  async function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

    //optional: Add validation

    if (isLogin) {
    } else {
      try {
        const result = await createUser(enteredEmail, enteredPassword);
        console.log(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className={classes.auth}>
      <h1>{isLogin ? "Login" : "Sign Up"}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className={classes.control}>
          <label htmlFor='email'>Your Email</label>
          <input type='email' id='email' required ref={emailInputRef} />
        </div>

        <div className={classes.control}>
          <label htmlFor='password'>Your Password</label>
          <input
            type='password'
            id='password'
            required
            ref={passwordInputRef}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button type='submit'>{isLogin ? "Login" : "Create Account"}</button>
          <button
            type='button'
            className={classes.toggle}
            onClick={switchAuthModeHandler}
          >
            {isLogin ? "Create new account" : "Login with existing account"}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Finally I have a function for hashing the password so it doesn't get stored as a string

```
"use client";
// components/LoginForm.js
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import classes from "./login.module.css";

async function createUser(email, password) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/route", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(data.message || "Something went wrong");
  }

  return data;
}

const LoginForm = () => {
  const emailInputRef = useRef();
  const passwordInputRef = useRef();
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);

  function switchAuthModeHandler() {
    setIsLogin((prevState) => !prevState);
  }

  async function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

    //optional: Add validation

    if (isLogin) {
    } else {
      try {
        const result = await createUser(enteredEmail, enteredPassword);
        console.log(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className={classes.auth}>
      <h1>{isLogin ? "Login" : "Sign Up"}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className={classes.control}>
          <label htmlFor='email'>Your Email</label>
          <input type='email' id='email' required ref={emailInputRef} />
        </div>

        <div className={classes.control}>
          <label htmlFor='password'>Your Password</label>
          <input
            type='password'
            id='password'
            required
            ref={passwordInputRef}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button type='submit'>{isLogin ? "Login" : "Create Account"}</button>
          <button
            type='button'
            className={classes.toggle}
            onClick={switchAuthModeHandler}
          >
            {isLogin ? "Create new account" : "Login with existing account"}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

And a function for connecting to the database with my login credentials

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
async function connectToDatabase() {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.<string>.mongodb.net/"
  );
  return client;
}
```

I omitted my real credentials but I copied and pasted them from the Mongodb website so I don't think that is part of the problem.

I tried changing my api/auth file to route.js and renaming the function to POST but I keep getting 404 not found as if Next thinks I'm trying to load an HTML page when I am trying to send a POST request to MongoDB. Most of this code was part of a tutorial but it was using an older version of Next JS. I was hoping I could get this to work and migrate from using better SQLite on my local storage to mongoDB on the cloud. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to revisit the URL that you are fetching with the POST request. If you have a `app/api/auth/route/route.js`, then the URL path `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/route` would work. Otherwise, try removing the `/route` at the end of your fetch URL.